# What is an elegant way to store a 2D field of blocks, that have attributes? (Without classes)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, enums, structure

I have a two dimensional array like this that stores the field of a small game:

```
'F = Forrest -> ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, notPassable
'G = Grass   -> ConsoleColor.Green, passable
'S = Sand    -> ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, passable
'W = Water   -> ConsoleColor.Cyan, notPassable
Dim level1(,) As String = {{"F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "F"},
                           {"F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "F"},
                           {"F", "F", "G", "W", "S", "G", "G", "G"},
                           {"G", "G", "W", "S", "S", "S", "F", "W"},
                           {"G", "G", "W", "S", "S", "G", "F", "W"},
                           {"F", "F", "G", "G", "S", "G", "F", "W"},
                           {"F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "F", "W"},
                           {"F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "F", "W"}}
```

Now I want to give those tiles attributes(more than one). So that I can use

```
level(1,1).color
level(1,1).isPassable
'etc
```

for example.

So instead of filling this with strings, I would like to fill it with structures? But it would look like a nightmare.

What would be a the best way to do this?

(I try to dodge classes for now, because I'm learning vb.net and we did not do much with classes yet.)

Comment: since this is primarily opinion-base and use case  based, my opinion is that you need a specialized class to handle you grid, whatever the grid cells may contain. Nothing prevents you from having a `MyArray(,) As Color` or, maybe better, a `List(Of Color())`. But this will require that you manage you Array/List somewhere else, having sparse code that implements all the logic required to make some use of the Array/LIst content. I, personally, always implement a Manager-Class that contains all the logic related to the Grid elements creation/position/modification/removal.

Comment: Something (simplified, here) like this: [Grid I can paint on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50513149/7444103).

Comment: Thx for that, very interesting. Studied it now some hours, but I still don't get it all TT. I just started learning vb.net, and did not much with classes yet. Would that not be possible without a class?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you just started programming, that code is probably not so simple to get at first. You could begin testing a simple `Array(,) Of Color` or `List(Of Color())` for now. More or less as shown in [Mary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156619/7444103). Change the colors to `System.Drawing.Color` if your app is not a Console one. This can work if the program is a simple. Move to Classes and `List(Of Class)` right after. Don't move until you have mastered :)  them.

Comment: `color(,) As Byte` and `isSolid(,) As Boolean` are never initiaized. Hence, a  `NullReferenceException ` is thrown. Since you're *upgrading* your initial Color *handler*, I sugget to ditch the `Structure` an use a `Class` direcly: `Public Class MyLevel Public Property Width As Integer (...) End Class`. Arrays are quite bad here, you should use `List(Of Color())` and a `List(Of Boolean())`. You can initialize a List to a specific size whenever you want. The learning curve might be somewhat steeper, but you're going to like what you can do with those objects.

Comment: Thx, I figured it out now with the initialization. It does now what I wanted. I'll take a look at lists next :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now with a structure and by using a parser to convert the array:

```
Private Structure Board
    Public color As Byte
    Public isPassable As Boolean
    'etc
End Structure

Sub Main()
    'F = Forrest -> ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, notPassable
    'G = Grass   -> ConsoleColor.Green, passable
    'S = Sand    -> ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, passable
    'W = Water   -> ConsoleColor.Cyan, notPassable
    Dim level1(,) As String = {{"F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G"},
                               {"F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G"},
                               {"F", "F", "G", "W", "S", "G"},
                               {"G", "G", "W", "S", "S", "S"},
                               {"G", "G", "W", "S", "S", "G"},
                               {"F", "F", "G", "G", "S", "G"},
                               {"F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G"},
                               {"F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G"}}

    Dim level(,) As Board
    level = ParseLevel(level1)

    'Data can now be accessed like this:
    'level(x, y).color // level(x, y).isPassable

    'Test
    For y As Integer = 0 To level.GetUpperBound(1)
        For x As Integer = 0 To level.GetUpperBound(0)
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x * 3, y)
            If level(x, y).isPassable Then
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Else
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            End If
            Console.Write($"{level(x, y).color:00} ")
        Next
    Next

    'Keep console open until input
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Function ParseLevel(input As String(,)) As Board(,)
    Dim output(input.GetUpperBound(1), input.GetUpperBound(0)) As Board 'swapping dimensions here

    For x As Integer = 0 To input.GetUpperBound(1)
        For y As Integer = 0 To input.GetUpperBound(0)
            Select Case input(y, x) 'swapping x and y here
                Case "F" 'Forrest
                    output(x, y).color = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen
                    output(x, y).isPassable = False
                    'etc
                Case "G" 'Grass
                    output(x, y).color = ConsoleColor.Green
                    output(x, y).isPassable = True
                    'etc
                Case "S" 'Sand
                    output(x, y).color = ConsoleColor.Yellow
                    output(x, y).isPassable = True
                    'etc
                Case "W" 'Water
                    output(x, y).color = ConsoleColor.Cyan
                    output(x, y).isPassable = False
                    'etc
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    Return output
End Function
```

I also noticed that an array stores x and y not the way I thought. So I swapped them while parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the data type of your array. A quick search/replace did the rest.

```
Private field(,) As ConsoleColor
    Private Sub FillArray()
        'F = Forrest -> ConsoleColor.DarkGreen
        'G = Grass   -> ConsoleColor.Green
        'S = Sand    -> ConsoleColor.DarkYellow
        'W = Water   -> ConsoleColor.Cyan
        field = {{ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen},
                {ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen},
                {ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Cyan, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green},
                {ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Cyan, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Cyan},
                {ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Cyan, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Cyan},
                {ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkYellow, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Cyan},
                {ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Cyan},
                {ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.Cyan}}
End Sub
```

Then to use your array

```
Sub Main()
        FillArray()
        Console.ForegroundColor = field(1, 1)
End Sub
```

No .color necessary.

Comment: That is what I mean with nightmare, it does look horrible to enter a level. And I want to store more than the color. .isSolid, .crossing_cost for example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set up a ***Game Board***. So, it is easier in OOP to think of that as an object. Here is one that I am very slowly working on.

Importantly, my array is oversized compared to the size of the game board. This makes checking for valid moves do not have to check for running off the edge of the array, only for blocking elements.

As you can see, I also reference `Piece`, which is a class/object like what you want to do with your field elements. This is still a work in progress and I am trying a few different ways to do things, hence the commented out code.

`pBoard` in the code below is the equivalent of your `field`.

```
Public Class Board
    Private pBoard(,) As Piece
    'Private pPieces As List(Of Piece)
    Private Const pEMPTYSPACE As PieceID = 0
    Private Const pBLOCK As PieceID = -1
    'Private pBlockPiece As New Piece(pBLOCK, PieceAlignment.Block, PieceListIndex.None)
    'Private pEmptyPiece As New Piece(pEMPTYSPACE, PieceAlignment.Null, PieceListIndex.None)


    Property UIElement As Control

    Public Structure PieceQuartet
        Dim QuartetSet As Boolean
        Dim North As Piece
        Dim South As Piece
        Dim West As Piece
        Dim East As Piece
        'Public ReadOnly Property HasValue As Boolean
        '    Get
        '        Return Not (North Is Nothing Or South Is Nothing Or West Is Nothing Or East Is Nothing)
        '    End Get
        'End Property
    End Structure

    Public Structure PieceLegalMovesQuartet
        Dim QuartetSet As Boolean
        Dim North As Boolean
        Dim South As Boolean
        Dim West As Boolean
        Dim East As Boolean
    End Structure

    Public Sub New(rows As Integer, columns As Integer) ', blockPiece As Piece)
        ReDim pBoard(rows + 2, columns + 2) ' 0-based, setting a strong boundary around the real board (1..8 or 1..10 matrix).
        ' set empty field
        For iterator1 = 0 To rows + 1
            For iterator2 = 0 To columns + 1
                pBoard(iterator1, iterator2) = EmptyPiece 'Nothing
            Next
        Next
        ' set boundaries
        For iterator1 = 0 To columns + 1
            pBoard(0, iterator1) = BlockPiece 'blockPiece
            pBoard(rows + 1, iterator1) = BlockPiece 'blockPiece
        Next
        For iterator1 = 0 To rows + 1
            pBoard(iterator1, 0) = BlockPiece 'blockPiece
            pBoard(iterator1, columns + 1) = BlockPiece 'blockPiece
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function AddPiece(row As Integer, column As Integer, piece As Piece) As Boolean
        Dim tVacant As Boolean
        tVacant = pBoard(row, column) Is Nothing OrElse pBoard(row, column).Alignment = PieceAlignment.Null
        If tVacant Then pBoard(row, column) = piece
        Return tVacant
    End Function

    Public Sub RemovePiece(row As Integer, column As Integer)
        pBoard(row, column) = EmptyPiece 'Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Function GetPiece(row As Integer, column As Integer) As Piece
        Return pBoard(row, column)
    End Function

    Public Function Neighbours(row As Integer, column As Integer) As PieceQuartet
        Dim tQuartet As New PieceQuartet
        If row <= 0 Or column <= 0 Or row >= pBoard.GetUpperBound(1) Or column >= pBoard.GetUpperBound(2) Then
            tQuartet = Nothing ' not allowed to be on or outside the boundary of the board.
        Else
            tQuartet.QuartetSet = True
            tQuartet.North = pBoard(row - 1, column)
            tQuartet.South = pBoard(row + 1, column)
            tQuartet.West = pBoard(row, column - 1)
            tQuartet.East = pBoard(row, column + 1)
        End If
        Return tQuartet
    End Function

    Function Neighbours(tuple As Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)) As PieceQuartet
        Return Neighbours(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hey, thx. Indeed, I want to make a simple console game. I learn vb.net atm. The problem is that I did not much with classes yet.