# Drawing an interactive grid with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there is any way to draw a GRID that detects when a tile is clicked in Visual Basic. i know its probably not meant for stuff like this but would realy help me if someone knew how!

Ill post an example image of what i want to achieve: 
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMWYf.jpg)

Comment: Use the Mouse events to determine your coordinates with a grid.

Comment: Hey, thank you. but im not sure how to even get a grid

Comment: Have you looked at the DataGridView control?

Comment: You use the paint event for the grid.  Just draw lines.  Post the code of your attempt.

Comment: A [Grid I can paint on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50513149/7444103). Read the notes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub drawControlsAsGrid()

    Dim cols As Integer = 20
    Dim rows As Integer = 30

    Dim w As Double = 26.5
    Dim h As Double = 25.4

    Dim basePanel As Panel = New Panel
    basePanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Me.Controls.Add(basePanel)
    basePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    basePanel.Width = Me.Width
    basePanel.Height = Me.Height
    basePanel.Location = New Point(0, 0)


    For i As Integer = 0 To cols
        For j As Integer = 0 To rows
            Dim newPanel As Panel = New Panel
            newPanel.Width = w
            newPanel.Height = h
            newPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            newPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            newPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            newPanel.Location = New Point(j * w, i * h)
            AddHandler newPanel.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                           MsgBox("Location.X : " & CType(sender, Control).Location.X &
                                                  "Location.Y : " & CType(sender, Control).Location.Y)
                                       End Sub



            basePanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)
        Next
    Next


End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    drawControlsAsGrid()
   End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! This perfect, thank you so much! Is there any way to change to code to remove the gaps between the tiles?

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. Yes replace  newPanel.Location = New Point(j * w + j * 5, i * h + i * 5) with  newPanel.Location = New Point(j * w, i * h)  just remove j*5 and i*5

Comment: Comeeeeeee oooon, for so little :). Thank you

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again, but there appears to be some inconsitance if you add more rows. do you know how to fix?  [image](https://i.imgur.com/m1UZFnV.png)

Comment: What do you mean? Can be more precise pls?

Comment: Sure, if you look at the image attached you will see the grid made by the program and the one thats already on the image in the background. att the top the two match 1/1 in position and in the bottem its different [image](https://i.imgur.com/m1UZFnV.png)

Comment: before you draw the new "grid" you must clean the basePanel parent control with something like this: basePanel.Parent.Controls.Clear

Comment: Im not sure if its clear what the issue, ill try to explain better.

Comment: [this](https://i.imgur.com/PjvT7q7.jpg) is the original image. i need the VS grid to line up perfectly with the grid on the image.

As you can [see](https://i.imgur.com/cNq7z0k.png) on the left it lines up but on the right it doesnt anymore

Comment: Yes, you need to set w and h value the same which has even tiles in background

Comment: I did, as you can [see](https://i.imgur.com/cNq7z0k.png) in this pic the tile on the left lines up perfect but the one on the right doesnt

Comment: Try to increase a little more 1 point or more. You must also consider the edges perhaps

Comment: Hey, yeah ive tried messing with the values but it always happens. it seems like the more rows i put in the more distance there is

Comment: and also, this probably isnt possible but do you know if there is a way for the edges of the grid to be black and the middle transparent

Comment: For that you just set as follows newPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent

Comment: Try now. I have update the code (based on your image background) :)

Comment: Ok ty will try it!

Comment: Ok that works for me! Ty alot for staying and helping :)

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun ;)