# Search Access Database in VB.Net Working Folder with Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

**Project Context**

I am working on a VB.Net project that combines a map creator with a database.It is built in line with these tutorials on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV2HFzbKOJI&t=195s).

The idea is to be able to click a square on the grid and have the appropriate database row be presented on the screen.

When the user clicks "Go" (see image at the bottom), this records the X and Y grid co-ordinates (see image top right). I accomplish this with the following Click Event:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

    'Associates click with colour for paintbrush

    If MouseX = 1 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 1 'BUILDING
    ElseIf MouseX = 5 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 2 'WATER
    ElseIf MouseX = 8 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 3 'ROAD
    ElseIf MouseX = 11 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 4 'FIELD
    ElseIf MouseX = 14 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 5 'WOODLAND
    ElseIf MouseX = 18 And MouseY = 22 Then
        Paintbrush = 6
    End If

    If MouseY <= 20 Then

        Select Case Paintbrush
            Case 0
            Case 1 ' Building 
                Map(mMapX, mMapY, 0) = 1
            Case 2 ' Water
                Map(mMapX, mMapY, 0) = 2
            Case 3 ' Road 
                Map(mMapX, mMapY, 0) = 3
            Case 4 ' Field
                Map(mMapX, mMapY, 0) = 4
            Case 5 ' Woodland 
                Map(mMapX, mMapY, 0) = 5
            Case 6 'Go
                CurrentLocationX = MouseX ' <<< This is the important part here
                CurrentLocationY = MouseY
                XLocation.Text = CurrentLocationX
                YLocation.Text = CurrentLocationY



        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

In the Access database (database="database"/table="twix"), which I have integrated into the project,I have X and Y Columns, one row for each square in the grid.

[image: X and Y columns in Database]

There is also a Primary Key column that has a unique number for each entry (which is the equivalent of the textbox top left in the 'Binding Navigator').

**Problem**

So my idea is that I can have it make a query (maybe SELECT. something?) based on the two variables stored in the textboxes at the top-right and spit out the appropriate row ID into the top-left textbox. I would then position this at the end of the click-event.

```
                    XLocation.Text = CurrentLocationX
                    YLocation.Text = CurrentLocationY
```

The end result is that the click command would make this query and update the "descriptions" of the map-grid location. I think I have all the necessary components here, I am just struggling to link the two systems (the grid and the database) up.

**Question**

I have looked around online, though I find the answers are all to case specific for me to salvage any code. What do I need to add to my ClickEvent to make the query to Database and refresh the records shown?

[image: Project Userform]

Comment: Possibly, build a class object that contains the Rectangle that defines the Cell and a reference to the corresponding DataRow, plus any other information you'll need when a Cell is selected. You can use `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` to determine which Cell was clicked. Something like this: [Grid I can paint on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50513149/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb    

Public Class Form1

    'Search Variables
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection

[...]

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        'Open Search Connection
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
        Source=C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Desktop\VisualBasic Stuff\GameFinal\Database.accdb"
        con.Open()

    [...]
    
    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    
 

    'Go
                        CurrentLocationX = MouseX
                        CurrentLocationY = MouseY
                        XLocation.Text = CurrentLocationX
                        YLocation.Text = CurrentLocationY
                        SearchSQL()
                        Current.Focus()
                        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                End Select
            End If
        End Sub

     [...]

 

    Private Sub SearchSQL()
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            ds.Tables.Add(dt)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID FROM Twix WHERE x =" & CurrentLocationX & " and y  =" & CurrentLocationY, con)
    
            da.Fill(dt)
            Current.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
            con.Close()
    
    
        End Sub
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.